# funcion no retorna valor python

Tags: python

Este es un simple programa que retorna cuando un numero es par o impar. Yo lo que quiero es practicar una funcion dentro de otra funcion por eso este sencillo programa.

Cada una de las funciones tienen sus respectivos argumentos .El modulo "retornoIfParOrImpar" va adentro del modulo "message_RetornoIfParOrImpar" y a la vez este ultimo va en un programa principal (en el cual no voy a usar el modulo "retornoIfParOrImpar" directamente sino que lo va a usar el modulo "message_RetornoIfParOrImpar.")

**Modulo message_RetornoIfParOrImpar:**

```
import retornoIfParOrImpar as nup
n=2
def retorno(n):
    if nup.par_impar(n) == 0:
        print("El numero es par")
    else:
        print ("El numero es impar")
```

**Modulo retornoIfParOrImpar**:

```
def par_impar(a):
    residuo = a%2
    return residuo
```

Mi pregunta es que estoy testeando el modulo "messageRetornoIfParOrImpar" y a pesar que no marca error en el IDE no imprime en pantalla. Puede ser que este declarando los argumentos de las funciones mal ?

Saludos a todos.

Comment: tomate el tiempo y provee un [mcve]

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, creo que deberías colocar mas información sobre lo que está pasando

Comment: ¿Dónde estas invocando a `retorno()`?

Comment: Bienvenido NIN a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad aumentando las chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Retorno lo voy a invocar en otro programa principal, aqui lo estoy solamente testeando. Pero en otro programa principal la variable "n" no va a ser 2 sino cualquier otra variable que quiera meter el usuario.

Comment: Hola NIN la única forma de que este código no imprima nada sin una excepción de por medio es que no estés llamando correctamnete a `retorno()` como Patricio comenta arriba y nos falta esta información.... Si no llamas a la función  como haces con `nup.par_impar(n)`  nada se va a ejecutar....

Comment: Muchas gracias Sevilla. Me di cuenta de eso. Que como yo estoy haciendo esto como parte de un programa principal y lo voy a invocar desde un programa principal pues no lo estaba invocando mientras lo testeaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy probando tu código y me funciona bien, debes verificar que cuando haces esto

```
import numPar as nup
```

estás importando un archivo, y ese archivo estrictamente se debe llamar numPar.py

Pruebas

[image: Test1]

[image: Test2]

[image: Test3]

Prueba esto

```
def retorno(n):
    x = nup.par_impar(n)
    if x == 0:
        print("El numero es par")
    else:
        print ("El numero es impar")
```

Comment: Ya lo actualice. Hubo un poqueno problema de edicion. Sin embargo sigue sin imprimirme nada en la pantalla

Comment: Pon tus archivos completos en la pregunta, en que SO estás?

Comment: IDE anaconda. Todos los modulos estan en la misma carpeta.

Comment: Python 3? o 2.7?

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, prueba el codigo del final

Comment: version 3. Quisiera aclarar algo. Me estoy dando cuanta que en la linea 13 hasta la linea 18 de tu "test.py" tienes unas lineas de codigo que yo no tengo. Puede significar eso que el problema es que no estoy invocando la funcion "retorno" ?

Comment: Si no tienes un lugar donde ejecutes retorno(n) jamas la estás ejecutando, y por ende jamas estás llamando a print

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Al poner las lineas de codigo finales de tu programa me di cuenta que como estoy testeando sin el programa principal no invocaba la funcion retorno por ningun lado. Otra cosa mas que he aprendido. Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: La ultima pregunta: me imprime en pantalla que el numero es par, sin ambargo me sale un error "name 'raw_input' is not defined"

Comment: darioxlz ya elimine el raw_input porque el problema es que en las nuevas versiones se renombro como input() solamente. Y como estoy usando un IDE spyder no hace falta el input() para que el programa quede abierto . Te agradesco muchisimo y a todos .

Comment: es correcto, yo uso python 2-7, esa funcion es obsoleta en versiones recientes